# How do I configure NancyFx to work with Spring.net?

Tags: c#, spring.net, nancy

I'm working on a REST-based webservice using NancyFx as the underlying framework. However, my assignment requires me to use Spring.Net for dependency injection. I'm not too experienced in C# (I have mostly been working on Java code prior to this assignment) or Spring itself quite yet, and I haven't been able to find a lot of information on making a custom bootstrapper using Spring as its IoC container, nor are there preconfigured bootstrappers like there are for Ninject or Unity.

Is there a good way to make Nancy and Spring play nice, or would I be better off going back to Microsoft's MVC framework for my assignment?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use spring.net? It's pretty much dead now-a-days...

Comment: @Phill Sadly yes. I'm building a proof of concept for a REST/MvC layer on a rather large application. This application uses spring and would, most likely, require a major rewrite to switch to another method of dependency injection. 
It's currently using Web forms for its views (my project is mostly intended to find alternatives for these), which is why I did have the option to choose which web framework I want to use for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip45,

isn't very complicated, but is toilful. Spring.Net is a declarative configuration container and TinyIoCContainer is a Register/Resolver container. Maybe on first look you can't see problems for difference of concepts, but generally, register/resolver containers will be filled automatically, on most cases discovering types to register them. 
To change NancyFx IoC Container you may derive from:

```
NancyBootstrapperWithRequestContainerBase<TContainer>
```

Implementing its abstract and virtual methods, it's easy, but you will need configure more then 60 object definitions. It's very complicated because if on new releases of NancyFx they create a new optional dependency, you will not be notified about it.

I'm now working to permit work with both containers, side by side, only hosting NancyModules on Spring.Net. Any specific of NancyFx infrastructure dependency still be discovered dynamically and registered on container like in the past.

One advice: if you use same strategy of me, does not send spring proxies to TinyIoCContainer, it crashes on initialization.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution by combining the suggestions of Christian Horsdal and Luiz Carlos Faria. I've now managed to get a working injected "Hello world" module through Nancy. What I ended up doing was make a `DualContainer` class with both an `IApplicationContext` and a  `TinyIoCContainer` included, and implementing them into a `NancyBootstrapperWithRequestContainerBase`. I used the TinyIoCContainer for the majority of the operations, with the Spring container only being called if there is a definition of the module in the object XML.

The way I implemented it does assume the module is registered under its class name however, so this is something to take into account.

The DualContainer class:

```
using Nancy.TinyIoc;
using Spring.Context;

namespace FORREST.WebService.General.Bootstrap
{
public class DualContainer
    {
        public TinyIoCContainer TinyIoCContainer { get; set; }
        public IApplicationContext ApplicationContext { get; set; }

        public DualContainer GetChildContainer()
        {
            return new DualContainer
            {
                TinyIoCContainer = TinyIoCContainer.GetChildContainer(),
                ApplicationContext = this.ApplicationContext
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Spring object definition (configSections is used for the database config, not used for this example):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net http://www.springframework.net/xsd/spring-objects.xsd">

      <object name="appConfigPropertyHolder" type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
        <property name="configSections">
          <value>appSettings</value>
        </property>
      </object>

      <object id="HelloWorldSpringRestModule" type="FORREST.WebService.RESTApi.Modules.HelloWorldSpringRestModule">
        <property name="Message" value="Hello World!"/>
      </object>

    </objects>
```

The custom bootstrapper (not the cleanest solution most likely, but it worked for me):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using Nancy.Bootstrapper;
using Nancy.TinyIoc;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Diagnostics;
using Spring.Context;
using Spring.Context.Support;

namespace FORREST.WebService.General.Bootstrap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class enabling the use of Spring injections in modules.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class HybridNancyBootstrapperBase : NancyBootstrapperWithRequestContainerBase<DualContainer>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default assemblies that are ignored for autoregister
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<Func<Assembly, bool>> DefaultAutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies = new Func<Assembly, bool>[]
            {
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("System.", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("System,", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("CR_ExtUnitTest", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("mscorlib,", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("CR_VSTest", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("DevExpress.CodeRush", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("IronPython", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("IronRuby", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("xunit", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("Nancy.Testing", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("MonoDevelop.NUnit", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("SMDiagnostics", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("CppCodeProvider", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("WebDev.WebHost40", StringComparison.InvariantCulture),
            };

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the assemblies to ignore when autoregistering the application container
        /// Return true from the delegate to ignore that particular assembly, returning true
        /// does not mean the assembly *will* be included, a false from another delegate will
        /// take precedence.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual IEnumerable<Func<Assembly, bool>> AutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies
        {
            get { return DefaultAutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the container using AutoRegister followed by registration
        /// of default INancyModuleCatalog and IRouteResolver.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container instance</param>
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(DualContainer container)
        {
            AutoRegister(container, this.AutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resolve INancyEngine
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>INancyEngine implementation</returns>
        protected override sealed INancyEngine GetEngineInternal()
        {
            return this.ApplicationContainer.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve<INancyEngine>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a default, unconfigured, container
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Container instance</returns>
        protected override DualContainer GetApplicationContainer()
        {
            return new DualContainer
            {
                ApplicationContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext(),
                TinyIoCContainer = new TinyIoCContainer()
            };              
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the bootstrapper's implemented types into the container.
        /// This is necessary so a user can pass in a populated container but not have
        /// to take the responsibility of registering things like INancyModuleCatalog manually.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationContainer">Application container to register into</param>
        protected override sealed void RegisterBootstrapperTypes(DualContainer applicationContainer)
        {
            applicationContainer.TinyIoCContainer.Register<INancyModuleCatalog>(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the default implementations of internally used types into the container as singletons
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to register into</param>
        /// <param name="typeRegistrations">Type registrations to register</param>
        protected override sealed void RegisterTypes(DualContainer container, IEnumerable<TypeRegistration> typeRegistrations)
        {
            foreach (var typeRegistration in typeRegistrations)
            {
                switch (typeRegistration.Lifetime)
                {
                    case Lifetime.Transient:
                        container.TinyIoCContainer.Register(typeRegistration.RegistrationType
                            , typeRegistration.ImplementationType).AsMultiInstance();
                        break;
                    case Lifetime.Singleton:
                        container.TinyIoCContainer.Register(typeRegistration.RegistrationType
                            , typeRegistration.ImplementationType).AsSingleton();
                        break;
                    case Lifetime.PerRequest:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to directly register a per request lifetime.");
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the various collections into the container as singletons to later be resolved
        /// by IEnumerable{Type} constructor dependencies.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to register into</param>
        /// <param name="collectionTypeRegistrations">Collection type registrations to register</param>
        protected override sealed void RegisterCollectionTypes(DualContainer container, IEnumerable<CollectionTypeRegistration> collectionTypeRegistrations)
        {
            foreach (var collectionTypeRegistration in collectionTypeRegistrations)
            {
                switch (collectionTypeRegistration.Lifetime)
                {
                    case Lifetime.Transient:
                        container.TinyIoCContainer.RegisterMultiple(collectionTypeRegistration.RegistrationType
                            , collectionTypeRegistration.ImplementationTypes).AsMultiInstance();
                        break;
                    case Lifetime.Singleton:
                        container.TinyIoCContainer.RegisterMultiple(collectionTypeRegistration.RegistrationType
                            , collectionTypeRegistration.ImplementationTypes).AsSingleton();
                        break;
                    case Lifetime.PerRequest:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to directly register a per request lifetime.");
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the given module types into the container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to register into</param>
        /// <param name="moduleRegistrationTypes">NancyModule types</param>
        protected override sealed void RegisterRequestContainerModules(DualContainer container, IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> moduleRegistrationTypes)
        {
            foreach (var moduleRegistrationType in moduleRegistrationTypes)
            {
                container.TinyIoCContainer.Register(
                    typeof(INancyModule),
                    moduleRegistrationType.ModuleType,
                    moduleRegistrationType.ModuleType.FullName).
                    AsSingleton();
                (container.ApplicationContext as IConfigurableApplicationContext).ObjectFactory.
                    RegisterResolvableDependency(moduleRegistrationType.ModuleType, 
                    container.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve(moduleRegistrationType.ModuleType));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Register the given instances into the container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to register into</param>
        /// <param name="instanceRegistrations">Instance registration types</param>
        protected override void RegisterInstances(DualContainer container, IEnumerable<InstanceRegistration> instanceRegistrations)
        {
            foreach (var instanceRegistration in instanceRegistrations)
            {
                container.TinyIoCContainer.Register(
                    instanceRegistration.RegistrationType,
                    instanceRegistration.Implementation);

                //Cast zodat het programmatisch kan worden gedaan
                (container.ApplicationContext as IConfigurableApplicationContext).ObjectFactory.RegisterResolvableDependency(
                    instanceRegistration.RegistrationType,
                    instanceRegistration.Implementation);            
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a per request child/nested container
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Request container instance</returns>
        protected override sealed DualContainer CreateRequestContainer()
        {
            return this.ApplicationContainer.GetChildContainer();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the diagnostics for initialisation
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>IDiagnostics implementation</returns>
        protected override IDiagnostics GetDiagnostics()
        {
            return this.ApplicationContainer.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve<IDiagnostics>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all registered startup tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> instance containing <see cref="IApplicationStartup"/> instances. </returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<IApplicationStartup> GetApplicationStartupTasks()
        {
            return this.ApplicationContainer.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveAll<IApplicationStartup>(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all registered request startup tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> instance containing <see cref="IRequestStartup"/> instances.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<IRequestStartup> RegisterAndGetRequestStartupTasks(DualContainer container, Type[] requestStartupTypes)
        {
            container.TinyIoCContainer.RegisterMultiple(typeof(IRequestStartup), requestStartupTypes);
            return container.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveAll<IRequestStartup>(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all registered application registration tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> instance containing <see cref="IRegistrations"/> instances.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<IRegistrations> GetRegistrationTasks()
        {
            return this.ApplicationContainer.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveAll<IRegistrations>(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve all module instances from the container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to use</param>
        /// <returns>Collection of NancyModule instances</returns>
        protected override sealed IEnumerable<INancyModule> GetAllModules(DualContainer container)
        {
            var nancyModules = container.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveAll<INancyModule>(false);
            return nancyModules;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retreive a specific module instance from the container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to use</param>
        /// <param name="moduleType">Type of the module</param>
        /// <returns>NancyModule instance</returns>
        protected override sealed INancyModule GetModule(DualContainer container, Type moduleType)
        {
            INancyModule module;
            try
            {
                module = (INancyModule) container.ApplicationContext.GetObject(moduleType.Name, moduleType);
            }
                //Niet geregistreerd in Spring, gebruik TinyIoCContainer om op te halen
            catch (Spring.Objects.Factory.NoSuchObjectDefinitionException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Laad " + moduleType.Name + " uit TinyIoC in plaats van Spring");
                container.TinyIoCContainer.Register(typeof(INancyModule), moduleType);
                module = container.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve<INancyModule>();
            }            
            return module;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes auto registation with the given container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container instance</param>
        private static void AutoRegister(DualContainer container, IEnumerable<Func<Assembly, bool>> ignoredAssemblies)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(NancyEngine).Assembly;
            container.TinyIoCContainer.AutoRegister(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a => !ignoredAssemblies.Any(ia => ia(a)))
                , DuplicateImplementationActions.RegisterMultiple, t => t.Assembly != assembly);
        }        
    }
}
```

And finally, the actual NancyModule:

```
using FORREST.WebService.General;
using FORREST.WebService.General.Modules;
using Nancy;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FORREST.WebService.RESTApi.Modules
{
    public class HelloWorldSpringRestModule : NancyModule
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Route_Base
        {
            get { return Configuratie.Api_Root + "/Hello"; }
        }

        public HelloWorldSpringRestModule()
        {
            Get[Route_Base] = HelloSpring;
        }

        protected internal Response HelloSpring(dynamic parameters)
        {
            var _response = (Response)(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Message));
            return _response;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

For now your best bet is to read this [bit of documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Writing-a-nancy-bootstrapper) and then draw inspiration from one of the other container specific bootstrappers found at the [Nancy Github organization](https://github.com/NancyFx)- e.g. the [Ninject one](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject/blob/master/src/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject/NinjectNancyBootstrapper.cs).
To verify the implementation you could run [the tests `NancyBootstrapperBase`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Tests/Unit/Bootstrapper/NancyBootstrapperBaseFixture.cs) against your new bootstrapper.

Hopefully in the future we will have better specs for the requirements for bootstrappers.